# In Ubuntu is there a way to select a specific 802.11 wireless mode (e.g. n or ac or ax)

Tags: wifi

I perform wireless testing for a company, and I would like to automate my testing of wireless access points (WAPs).  One of the tests is to connect clients with different Wi-Fi modes and check interop and then performance of the WAP.  I would like to write a script so that my test client (a laptop with Intel AX210 chip) can connect to the WAP with all modes (802.11 b/g/n/a/ac/ax).  The closest thing I can find is being able to select which band by editing the .nmconnection file under /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections.  I have tried looking through various stackexchange forums and other sites/blogs/forums but can't find an answer.

I am using Linux Mint and using NetworkManager, but am open to any sort of answer that I can use scripting to accomplish.  I am not looking for someone to write the script, but just looking for a command or a parameter in a config file, and I will do the rest.

I've tried using all sorts of commands to even try and see the Wi-Fi mode but I cannot (commands like iw, lspci).  In Windows, I can use  `netsh wlan show int` and it'll tell me which mode.  The problem is that I need this to be a script I can run and I don't know how to change wireless modes using a script in Windows.

I know this is a Unix/Linux forum, but if this isn't possible with Linux and possible with Windows, then if someone can point me to how I can change wireless modes using CLI in Windows, that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: It's going to depend on the capabilities of the specific device and its kernel driver (iwlwifi?) I think - see for example [What is "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" in WiFi setting?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1099673/178692)